# Convert binary String[] to int[] java

Tags: java

If I want to convert binary String[] to binary int[], in which part I made a mistake, because I got wrong result?

I have binary string array like this: {"010101","000011","111100"}
I want to convert it to binary integer array with the same result: {"010101","000011","111100"}

I tried but the result is not as my expectation. Here is my code:

```
public class StringArr2IntArr {
static int[] sAtoiA;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] str=new String[]{"010101","000011","111100"};
    System.out.println("String arr: ");
    for (String str1 : str) {
        System.out.println("strArr= "+str1);
    }

    sAtoiA = convertStringArraytoIntArray(str);
    System.out.println("sA to iA:");
    for (int iA : sAtoiA) {
        System.out.println("iArr= "+iA);
    }
}

private static int[] convertStringArraytoIntArray(String[] sArr) {
    if (sArr!=null) {
        int[] iArr=new int[sArr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++) {
            iArr[i]=Integer.parseInt(sArr[i]);
        }
        return iArr;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Because I got result:

```
String arr: 
strArr= 010101
strArr= 000011
strArr= 111100
sA to iA:
iArr= 10101
iArr= 11
iArr= 111100
```

The results should be:

```
String arr: 
strArr= 010101
strArr= 000011
strArr= 111100
sA to iA:
iArr= 010101
iArr= 000011
iArr= 111100
```

The point is the result should be same before and after converter. 
Is there somebody can help me?

Comment: Did you even *glance* at the documentation of the classes you're using? What does [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) do? Is there, I don't know, an [alternative to it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) that does something closer to what you want?

Comment: Integer.parseInt(sArr[i]) method will return you integer equivalent of given string. so if you pass 010101 as argument then its integer equivalent will be 10101. it will wipe out leading zeros cause in decimal representation we just remove out leading zeros for a number

Comment: Please do not edit incorrect tags back in that people have kindly removed for you. A) Your code doesn't use any `ArrayList`s. B) Even if it did, it has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: In short, you forgot to tell it that the strings are binary rather than decimal. It can't guess  whether you mean 1010₁₀ or 1010₂.

Answer (score 3):

With some tweaks,
this produces the output as you described:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] str = new String[]{"010101", "000011", "111100"};
    System.out.println("String arr: ");
    for (String str1 : str) {
        System.out.println("strArr= " + str1);
    }

    sAtoiA = convertStringArraytoIntArray(str);
    System.out.println("sA to iA:");
    for (int iA : sAtoiA) {
        System.out.println("iArr= " + String.format("%6s", Integer.toString(iA, 2)).replaceAll(" ", "0"));
    }
}

private static int[] convertStringArraytoIntArray(String[] sArr) {
    if (sArr != null) {
        int[] iArr = new int[sArr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < sArr.length; i++) {
            iArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(sArr[i], 2);
        }
        return iArr;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Janos! But how if the binary string is dynamic? I mean, if the content not always have length 6?

Comment: if you want to support different kinds of lengths, then you should have given more relevant input+output examples

Comment: However, keep in mind that an `int[]` cannot carry the information of the original lengths. So what you want might not be possible at all, conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you convert a value in an integer, which is a number and does not support leading 0's. So, it cuts them off. If you want to use this sequence of number I would recommend to keep working with your strings and extract the digits when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Integer.parseInt` parses number by default in base10. You also have a method where you can specify the base the number is in: `Integer.parseInt(theString, 2)`. When you do it this way however, converting it back requires additional work, since integers are represented by default in base10 when you print them out. So to convert them back you need the method `Integer.toBinaryString(theInteger)`. The method does get rid of leading zeros so the representation does not stay the same. You can fix this by formatting the binary string:

```
int length = 8;
String result = String.format("%" + length + "s").replaceAll(" ", "0");
```